# How do I show the separability of this density matrix?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

I am stuck since a longer time regarding this exercise where I need to work with a density matrix of the given form

$$\displaystyle \rho_{AB}(X)= \frac{1}{N+\text{tr}X^2}\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
    I & X \\
   X & X^2 \\
  \end{array} } \right)$$

where $X$ is an $N\times N$ hermitian matrix in the quantum system $B$ with the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^N$, $I$ is the identity matrix and $\rho_{AB}$ a state on the quantum system $AB$ with Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^N$.

**Question**: How do I show now, that $\rho_{AB}(X)$ is separable by using the spectral theorem on $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|i\rangle$ be the eigenbasis of the Hilbert space of system B which diagonalizes $X$

$$
X = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i |i\rangle\langle i|
$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and define

$$
|\psi_k\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x_k^2}} (|0\rangle + x_k |1\rangle)
$$

$$
\rho_k = |\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k| = \frac{1}{1 + x_k^2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_k \\
x_k & x_k^2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now, note that

$$
\rho_{AB}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i \rho_i \otimes |i\rangle\langle i|\tag1
$$

where

$$
\lambda_i = \frac{1 + x_i^2}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2}
$$

and the right hand side of $(1)$ is separable.

---

In order to see the equality $(1)$, consider each of the four blocks of the matrix $\rho_{AB}(X)$ in turn. The top left block is

$$
\langle 0|\rho_{AB}(X)|0\rangle = \frac{1}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} I.
$$

The bottom right block is

$$
\langle 1|\rho_{AB}(X)|1\rangle = \frac{x_i^2}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} \sum_{i=1}^N |i\rangle\langle i| = \frac{1}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i|i\rangle\langle i| x_i|i\rangle\langle i| = \frac{1}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} X^2.
$$

The top right block is

$$
\langle 0|\rho_{AB}(X)|1\rangle = \frac{x_i}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} \sum_{i=1}^N |i\rangle\langle i| = \frac{1}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i|i\rangle\langle i| = \frac{1}{N + \mathrm{tr}X^2} X
$$

and similarly for the bottom left block.

Comment: Should $\rho_k$ in $(1)$ be $\rho_i$, right? Otherwise, this is very intriguing and helpful.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for catching! Fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the other answer was deleted. Have you seen it? I don't think that $\rho_{AB}$ describes a pure state, as it was claimed before

Comment: I saw it only briefly, but I agree with you that $\rho_{AB}$ is not pure. An easy counterexample is $X=I$ where we get $\mathrm{tr}(\rho_{AB}(I)^2) = \frac{1}{N}$. More generally, if $\rho_{AB}$ were pure, then the matrix would be rank one. However, the identity block makes this impossible as can be seen by considering linear independence of say the first two rows.

Comment: when taking a look at the matrix elements by examining $\langle n| \rho_{AB}|m\rangle$, do you use the fact that $\langle{n}|{jl}\rangle = \delta_{n,j} \forall l$ ? If so this would be counted as a measurement on the system $A$, or am I wrong?

Comment: Re first question: yes, though - assuming $n$ and $j$ refer to basis elements in Hilbert space of system $A$ and $l$ refers to basis elements in Hilbert space of system $B$ - the relationship is $\langle n|jl\rangle = \delta_{n,j} |l\rangle$. You can see this by writing $|jl\rangle = |j\rangle |l\rangle$.

Comment: Re second question: I am not regarding this as a measurement. It is merely a mathematical procedure for establishing equality of two matrices (they are equal if and only if all their elements are equal).

Comment: First: So the representation of $\rho_{AB}$ is in the picture of $A$ when I understand correctly?
Secondly: I got this, I was just trying to get the physical Intuition behind this. I am more concerned why the upper left matrix element shouldnt be $\langle 00 | \rho_{AB} | 00 \rangle$ if you get me now.

Comment: First: What do you mean when you say "in the picture of $A$"? Second: I see. The answer is: to an extent. In general, measurement in quantum mechanics is more complicated than reading off matrix entries. However, in the specific case of diagonal elements $\langle n,m|\rho_{AB}|n,m\rangle$ does give you the probability of obtaining $|n\rangle$ and $|m\rangle$ when measuring both subsystems.

Comment: First: Well, since the sandwiching states $|n \rangle = |n \rangle_A$ you are using for the matrix elements are in the Hilbert space of System $A$, I meant this is in "the picture of $A$". Second: Yes, that was what I was having in mind. Thanks about that!

Comment: Regarding the reason $\langle 00|\rho_{AB}|00\rangle$ is the top left element of $\rho_{AB}$: recall that given an operator $A$, its matrix $M(A)$ is defined to be the table of numbers $a_{ij}$ where $a_{ij}$ is the coefficient in front of $|i\rangle$ when expressing $A|j\rangle$ in the given basis. Moreover, in an inner product space - which we are in - we can compute those coefficients using inner product, so $a_{ij} = \langle i|A|j\rangle$. Thus, top left element is $\langle 00|\rho_{AB}|00\rangle$, because $|0\rangle$ is the first element of the basis (for both subsystems).

Comment: Sandwiching a two-system density operator $\rho_{AB}$ between kets on the first subsystem gives you the blocks of $\rho_{AB}$. You can think of this as filtering the elements of the product basis on $AB$ to only those product states with a given ket on $A$. For example, $\langle 1|\rho_{AB}|1\rangle$ "filters" the basis to only include states with $|1\rangle$ on subsystem $A$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and comments. You are great! :)